# Python: Can I import slice of a json file with urllib?

Tags: python, json, urllib

I'm trying to import some JSON data into Python with urllib and json.load but I want to cut out the first x and the last y characters because it's making the json data invalid.

```
thePage = urllib.urlopen("http://datafile.dat")
myData = json.load(thePage)
```

I want to do something like json.load(thePage[10:-10]), but since urlopen doesn't return a string, I can't slice it. What can I do?

Comment: You can add `.read()` at the end of urlopen() to get all the text from the request. Then you can slice it normally. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: I don't think so because once I convert the opened webpage to a string, json.load won't accept it as an argument (as I understand it anyways, not much experience with programming sadly)

Comment: Hmm, try `json.loads` instead

Comment: Wow, that was easy :) thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem :). Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text from the request by doing `.read()`. With this, you should use `json.loads()` instead of `json.load()`, as you're inputting a string as a parameter.

You can do your normal slicing if necessary with the HTML as a string.